# having a user set the href value through javascript - xss

Tags: javascript, html, xss

So I have to let users add their own links dynamically by clicking some buttons ( javascript ).

javascript:

```
if (IsStringAUrl(url)) {
    url = encodeURI(url); //YES YES I ALSO ESCAPE THE ' CHAR, JUST BEING LAZY HERE
    document.getElementById("mylink").href = url;
}
```

Do I need to worry for being xss-ed with this code? I ask because right here:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.235_-_URL_Escape_then_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_URL_Attribute_Subcontext_within_the_Execution_Context

it says that i also need to run that "encodeforjavascript". On a second thought, that function seems like it is needed ONLY for files created via some server side language? (php,java) Am I right on this ?

p.s. while reading what encodeforjavascript does on OWASP's site, it was fun to note that in their own site they don't escape their own strings!

http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#encodeForJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29

the example they provide is not visible because they haven't escaped, you have to VIEW SOURCE to view it :)

EDIT: Obviously the link is not confined to a single user (or else my question would have no point in existing), it gets saved in the DB and made public.

Comment: **Warning**: This question is misleading: In comments on my now-deleted answer, the OP says that in addition to the above, he's also saving the link in a DB and re-serving it to other users. So, something completely different from the question above. -1 for wasting people's time.

Answer (score 1):

An extra check would be:

```
if (url.indexOf("javascript") == 0) {
  url = url.replace("javascript", "");
}
```

Comment: then you don't need to worry about anything else I think

Comment: They don't even need to worry about this. If a user wants to execute JavaScript on the page, they don't need the page to enable that. They can just use a bookmarklet or open the web console.

Comment: But according to the OP's comments on my now-deleted answer, the OP didn't bother to tell us that he's also saving the information to a DB and reserving it to other users.